# Fixing a div at bottom after the end of its content where other div's content is scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have parent div with class name "container" and two child div with name "pitem" and "aside". pitem has a property "display:grid" and aside has a property "display:block". aside div has less content then pitem div. So, I want to fix the aside div at bottom when it finishes it's content while pitem div will scroll to its content.

```
.aside {
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

is not working....

Comment: the both div has "overflow-y: auto" and just want to stop one scrolling div where other will scroll till then....

Comment: try `position:sticky` with `top:0;` for aside.